# Objective-C Float Rounding

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, floating-point, rounding

How might I round a float to the nearest integer in Objective-C:

Example:

```
float f = 45.698f;
int rounded = _______;
NSLog(@"the rounded float is %i",rounded);
```

should print "the rounded float is 46"

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The recommended way is in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4702539/308315

---

Original answer:

cast it to an int after adding 0.5.

So

```
NSLog (@"the rounded float is %i", (int) (f + 0.5));
```

Edit: the way you asked for:

```
int rounded = (f + 0.5);


NSLog (@"the rounded float is %i", rounded);
```

Comment: This will only produce a _downward_ rounding. To get < .5 rounds down and >= .5 rounds up: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", (int)round(f)]

Comment: actually no. This will produce the nearest rounding.

Comment: This does not handle negative numbers properly.

Comment: Example: -2.8 rounded should be -3, but with your formula we have -2.8 + 0.5 = -2.2, cast to int is -2

Comment: @HaryantoCiu What is "nearest rounding"

Comment: If you use unsigned int or NSUInteger  it is probably correct answer (and could be even little more efficient than using C's function, but it anyway would be MICRO-optimailisation) Am I correct or not ?

Comment: this works in some conditions but not a 100% correct answer. @Jonathan Grynspan and "Arvind Kanjariya" provided better and authentic answers.
thanks

Answer (score 153):

Use the C standard function family `round()`. `roundf()` for `float`, `round()` for `double`, and `roundl()` for `long double`. You can then cast the result to the integer type of your choice.

Comment: I think this is better and more efficient way to do it.

Comment: Unlike the + 0.5 method, this does handle negative numbers properly.

Comment: Hey @JonathanGrynspan lots of answers around are linking to your answer here - would be great to expand it with some examples of how (and why) to use each.

Answer (score 12):

For round `float` to nearest integer use `roundf()`

```
roundf(3.2) // 3
roundf(3.6) // 4
```

You can also use `ceil()` function for always get upper value from `float`.

```
ceil(3.2) // 4
ceil(3.6) // 4
```

And for lowest value `floor()`

```
floorf(3.2) //3
floorf(3.6) //3
```

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to round a float in objective-c is `lroundf`:

```
float yourFloat = 3.14;
int roundedFloat = lroundf(yourFloat); 
NSLog(@"%d",roundedFloat);
```

Comment: No, easiest is add 0.5 and truncate.  You don't have to remember "lroundf" to do that, and you know exactly what you're getting.

Comment: @Hot Licks - Unless of course you require rounding of both positive and negative numbers (my case) where the 0.5 method is flawed.

Answer (score 4):

Check the manual page for `rint()`

Answer (score 3):

If in case you want round float value in integer below is the simple method for rounding the float value in objective C.

```
int roundedValue = roundf(Your float value);
```

Answer (score 0):

let's do tried and checkout

```
//Your Number to Round (can be predefined or whatever you need it to be)
float numberToRound = 1.12345;
float min = ([ [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%.0f",numberToRound] floatValue]);
float max = min + 1;
float maxdif = max - numberToRound;
if (maxdif > .5) {
    numberToRound = min;
}else{
    numberToRound = max;
}
//numberToRound will now equal it's closest whole number (in this case, it's 1)
```

Comment: I think this answer is much more helpful than any of above according to the question asked..