# Round up or down

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, math

I have a float which I'd like to round up or down to the nearest integer.

For example:

1.4 = 1.0
1.77 = 2.0
1.1 = 1.0

etc...

I'm doing this in Objective C, so I guess I need a standard math function... Would nearbyintf do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C Float Rounding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702408/objective-c-float-rounding) or [How to round off float values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594116/objective-c-how-to-round-off-float-values)

Comment: @andrewx I downvoted your answer, for reasons I explained in the comment. Whether or not it is "taught in many books", your recommendation to rely on casting is poor advice.

Answer (score 8):

You can use any of the standard C library math functions defined in `math.h`. `nearbyintf` would work, as would `roundf` or `ceilf` or `floorf`, depending on what you want.

Xcode will show you the documentation (UNIX manual page) for these functions if you option-double-click them in the editor.

Answer (score 4):

use

```
double a = 2.3;
double b = round(a);
```

You can find round and other math functions in math.h

Answer (score 2):

Whenever rounding, consider whether negative numbers are possible.  If so, the traditional int (int) (x + 0.5) may not do what you want and the round function may be better. For example, round (-1.5) = 2.

Answer (score 0):

Rounding is very easy to implement, as casting a value as an `int` truncates the decimal part of the number. Let `0 <= x < 1`. Then if you want all values to round down to the nearest integer if the decimal part is less than `x`, and round up to the nearest integer if the decimal part is greater than or equal to `x`, then you need only calculate:

```
int roundedValueBasedOnX = (int) (value + (1 - x));
```

As an example, if `x = 0.2`, then we have:

**1)** `value = 9.4`, should round to `10`.

```
int roundedValueBasedOnX = (int) (9.4 + (1 - 0.2)) = (int) (9.4 + 0.8) = (int) (10.2) = 10;
```

**2)** `value = 3.1`, should round to `3`.

```
int roundedValueBasedOnX = (int) (3.1 + (1 - 0.2)) = (int) (3.1 + 0.8) = (int) (3.9) = 3;
```

If `x = 0.7`, then we have:

**3)** `value = 9.4`, should round to `9`.

```
int roundedValueBasedOnX = (int) (9.4 + (1 - 0.7)) = (int) (9.4 + 0.3) = (int) (9.7) = 9;
```

**4)** `value = 3.8`, should round to `4`.

```
int roundedValueBasedOnX = (int) (3.8 + (1 - 0.7)) = (int) (3.8 + 0.3) = (int) (4.1) = 4;
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score -2):

The old-school way would be to add 0.5 to the number and then let it truncate:

```
int x = (int) (someFloat + 0.5);
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't take into account negative numbers (and if it did, you'd basically be rewriting the `roundf` function).