# Make a float only show x decimal places before dot

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have the value 25.00 in a float
How can I display the value with x number before dot.
Number after dot can be format with "%.xf" (x is number after dot)
But how can i print like this with "%4.2f"
25.00 -> 0025.00
123.12 -> 0123.12

Comment: FYI - Look into `NSNumberFormatter` instead of using a string format. This will give better output based on the user's locale.

Comment: Check my answer for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332849/is-there-any-easy-way-to-round-a-float-with-one-digit-number-in-objective-c/47348309#47348309 it will help you.

Answer (score 3):

Use a format string like this: `%07.2f` where `7` is the total length of the output (including the decimal point) and `2` is the number of digits after the decimal. The `0` causes leading zeros to be used to pad the number (instead of spaces).

```
let str1 = NSString(format: "%07.2f", 25.00)  // str1 = "0025.00"
let str2 = NSString(format: "%07.2f", 123.12) // str2 = "0123.12"
```

Comment: Should mention that the `0` in the format means that the value will be padded with zeros to fill an remaining space. Without the `0` the extra room will be filled with spaces.