# Rounding up double, if greater or equal to .5, in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, double, rounding

How do I round the following values in Objective-C (they're doubles):

```
1.1 -> 1.0
1.6 -> 2.0
1.5 -> 2.0
2.3 -> 2.0
2.0 -> 2.0
2.001 -> 2.0
```

I'm having issues differentiating between various less than and more than or equal to `.5` values.

Comment: Dont tag extra languages for visibility's sake. Thanks

Comment: Without using a `round` type function this type of rounding is typically done using `double(int(x + 0.5))`

Comment: Update your question with the code you have tried so people can show you what to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To round up a variable you can generally add 0.5 and then either cast the result to `int` (and back to `float` or `double` if you like), or call the `floor()` function to truncate the fractional part.

Answer (score 1):

From: [Objective-C Float Rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702408/objective-c-float-rounding/4702539#4702539)

> Use the C standard function family round(). roundf() for float,
>   round() for double, and roundl() for long double. You can then cast
>   the result to the integer type of your choice.